# Disable SSL certificate check on App level on iOS app

Tags: ios, ssl-certificate

i am using google map sdk for iOS and using GMSTile services.
i want to place custom tile on map from my server.
i am using HTTPS url for same.
the url provided to GMSURLTileLayer and google download the tile automatically according to BBOX.
but in my case it is not downloaded . the Https request not reaching  at my  server due to invalid certificate.

How i will disable Certificate check for https request at Application level.